# "Unable to connect to the local runtime" in google colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to connect local run time but it's not connecting,

I used the troubleshooting dialog following commands:

```
pip install jupyter_http_over_ws
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws

jupyter notebook \ --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com --port=8888 \--NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

Have tried the same above steps as said in below URL 
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Facing an issue 'Jupyter authentication cookie was not detected'
Tried by disabling adblocker, antivirus and also using different port numbers. Below was the solution given by team

Navigate to http://localhost:8888 in a separate browser tab and follow the provided instructions. This will set a browser cookie used for authentication between the browser and the Jupyter notebook server.

But when I open the URL, it asks for a password(already set up) and then no further instructions are appearing.

Comment: Do you get an error ?

Comment: I didn't get an error but I'm not able to connect local runtime

Answer (score 7):

This issue was raised in Github issues for Collaboratory:
This answer helped me https://github.com/googlecolab/jupyter_http_over_ws/issues/1#issuecomment-557469128

According to this issue

start the jupyter notebook with the below command.

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --NotebookApp.port_retries=0 --notebook-dir="" --no-browser --allow-root --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf=True --port=8888
```

then open the notebook by going to this URL.

```
localhost:8888
```

> according to [kris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123555/kris) This may allow you to connect, but it basically disables all security features.

Then retry connecting to local runtime with Google Colab

If it does not solve your problem then try disabling AdBlock extension or app.

Comment: This may allow you to connect, but it basically disables all security features.

Comment: Thank you!!
In my case the issue was with UBlock origin, disabling it for google colab fixes the issue

Answer (score 5):

**For Windows (10/11)**

**Method 1: Using git bash**

follow these steps
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

[image: Using git bash]

**Method 2: Using Windows terminal & Multiline commands**

*Install jupyter_http_over_ws*

```
pip install jupyter_http_over_ws
```

*enable the jupyter_http_over_ws jupyter extension (one-time)*

```
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
```

*Use multiline commands to start server and authenticate*

```
jupyter notebook ^
  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' ^
  --port=8888 ^
  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

[image: Using mutilines & Windows terminal]

**Method 3: Using single-line command & windows terminal**

*Install jupyter_http_over_ws*

```
pip install jupyter_http_over_ws
```

*enable the jupyter_http_over_ws jupyter extension (one-time)*

```
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
```

*Use single-line commands to start server and authenticate*

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

[image: Using Single line and windows terminal]

Once the server has started, it will print a message with the initial backend URL used for authentication. Make a copy of this URL as you'll need to provide this in the next step.

[image]

**Connect to the local runtime**
In Colaboratory, click the "Connect" button and select "Connect to local runtime...". Enter the URL from the previous step in the dialog that appears and click the "Connect" button. After this, you should now be connected to your local runtime.

[image]

Comment: In my case, it was port sensitive. I needed to kill another process which was running on port 8888.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why a local connection might fail. To gather more diagnosis information, click the 'troubleshoot' link in the notification that appears in the lower left of the screen.

It will look like this:
[image]

I'd recommend following whatever steps are recommended there. If you get stuck, please update your original question with the diagnosis offered in the troubleshooting dialog.

Comment: I have used Troubleshoot commands only but still I'm not able to connect

Comment: More information will be helpful to diagnose. For example: What adjustments were recommended by the troubleshoot command? How did you change your invocation? What error are you observing? Is your Jupyter backend running locally, or are you attempting to connect remotely via an SSH tunnel?

Comment: When I run Troubleshoot command Jupyter browser is opening but Colab is not connecting to local runtime again its showing Troubleshooting dialog